# Retrieving and displaying time and date stored in UTC with Python

Tags: python, date

I have a scraper running that scrape data from a remote site, and the data is stored in a SQLite DB, and timestamped with a integer UNIX timestamp in UTC, because I thought it is a good idea.

```
    time = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
```

However, when I attempted to fetch data and retrieve in local time (Kuala Lumpur, UTC+8) I got a lot of mismatch. For retrieving I tried converting local time back to UTC in Python (3.6.6), but none of them seem to be fetching rows with the right timestamp. My last attempt to find the start of a given day, before giving up was

```
(datetime(the_date.year,
          the_date.month,
          the_date.day,
          tzinfo=timezone.utc)
 - timedelta(hours=8)).timestamp()
```

My last attempt to convert timestamp fetched from the database to local time was

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) + timedelta(hours=8)
```

They didn't somehow match with each other, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Is there daylight saving in KL timezone? If so, using UTC-time is much harder than local time, however in db you should use UTC, especially if you plan for global reach. Try pytz: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: no, we don't observe dst (phew). Yes that was what I felt I should be doing by saving time in UTC format. But some how something is wrong with my code somewhere because they don't really match. What I retrieved doesn't seem to match my expectation, and after converting the retrieved time back to local time nothing seems to match at all.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you:

```
def get_UTC_diff(tzname):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    tz = timezone(tzname)
    utc = timezone('UTC')
    utc.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
    delta = utc.localize(now) - tz.localize(now)
    hrs = int(delta.seconds / 3600)
    return hrs
```